# jquery hover animate is not working

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({'color' : 'red'}, "fast");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'color' : 'white'}, "fast");
    });
});
```

I want the color of the text within the h1 tag to turn red when I hover over it. When the mouse leaves the h1 tag I want to text to turn white again. Could somebody please fix my code?

Comment: You have to include jQuery UI script.

Comment: which parts are working and which aren't? have you tested to make sure the selector is functioning and either of the hover functions are firing?

Comment: @Maslow All he needs is jQuery UI. His script is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
:

> Note: The [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) project extends the `.animate()` method by allowing some **non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated**. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.

Include jQuery UI in your page after jQuery is loaded:

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js
```

Your `<head>` will look like this:

```
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!-- Load jQuery UI -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Then the animation will work.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQpMz/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate colors with just jQuery.

In order to animate colors, you need to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Using the following HTML:

```
<h1>A header</h1>
<h1>Another header</h1>
<h1>And another header</h1>
<h2>A h2</h2>
```

and your Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({color : 'red'}, "fast");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({color : 'white'}, "fast");
    });
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DBesa/).